# AVSpeechSynthesizer,AVSpeechUtterance can't work on the iPhone 5s with iOS9.2.1(13D15) or iOS9.1.1

Tags: ios

I want to make a simple TTS(TextToSpeech) on `iOS` with `AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h` and I tried to go with `AVSpeechSynthesizer,AVSpeechUtterance`.

However the iPhone 5s with `iOS9.2.1(13D15)` or `iOS9.1.1` can't speech the text and without any voice. At the same time, it can work on iPhoto 6 or 6Plus with `iOS9.2.1`.

Who can tell me the reason about that ?(I build the App with Xcode 7.2) Thanks!